# Getting error in the stock item browser in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am converting my custom package from Acumatica 20R2 to 21R1 and I am trying to solve an issue for quite some time.
I have added an Extension Table to the Inventory item to store all my custom fields. When I try to load the Stock Item browser and I am getting the following error

**Error: The entry form (ID: IN202500, title: Style Master (Item)) cannot be automated. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I have redesigned the screen again and still facing the same issue.

I have totally removed the stock item page from the customization package and rebuild the project with my custom dll and still, I am facing the same issue.

**This works perfectly in 20R2**
The Extension table having 180 fields.

How to debug and fix the issue?

**Update**

I have tested it on 21R2. It is working fine. Looks like issue is in 21R1.

```
[PXTable(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID),
   IsOptional = true)]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[PXCacheName("InfoInventoryItemAttributeExtNV")]
public class InfoInventoryItemAttributeExtNV : PXCacheExtension<InventoryItem>
{
    #region SearchType
    [PXDBString(1, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXDefault("J", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Search Group")]
    [PXStringList(new[] { "J", "D", "G", "N" },
                   new[] { "Jewelry", "Diamond", "Gemstone", "None" })]
    public virtual string SearchType { get; set; }
    public abstract class searchType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<searchType> { }
    #endregion
 ----
}
```

Comment: If the error is not occurring on a new Acumatica website you likely still have customized elements corrupting it. Try removing every part of your customizations one by one to identify which element is breaking the page.

Comment: This works fine in 20R2 & 21R2. Looks like issue in 21R1

Comment: This might be a workflow issue. Unfortunately I can't provide more information. Any idea what is the exact customization item breaking the base product?

Answer (score 0):

Look for ***Automation screen="IN202500"*** on your project XML. Make a copy of your customisation project and then remove the element and republish. Had the same issue once where I don't use the automation, but the section was auto-added onto the project XML